# How to write T-SQL query to Pivot data as below?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table named "emp" like below image:

[image]

I tried Pivot query but I am not aggregating any columns. Then How can I achieve this result with T-SQL?

The query I am trying is like this:

```
SELECT id, empID, Eclass. StartTime, EndTime, TypeCode
FROM
   (SELECT id, empID, Eclass, code, Etype FROM emp) AS e
PIVOT(SUM(id) FOR code IN(StartTime, EndTime, TypeCode) AS pvt
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post the data not screen shots.  See here for how to post good question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You really need to post your current SQL, otherwise all anyone can do is give you pseudocode examples which probably won't work for you.

Comment: Edited my question and posted query I tried. please see my question. Pseudo code is fine too. hard to post data...its huge

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jiacheng Gao's idea of using `MAX()` for pivot and some MSDN documentation, I came up with the following query :

```
SELECT id,empID,Eclass AS EType,[StartTime] AS StartTime,[EndTime] AS EndTime, [Type Code] AS [Type Code]
  FROM
  (SELECT id,empID,Eclass,Code,Etype 
    FROM DATA ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX(Etype)
    FOR Code IN ([StartTime],[EndTime],[Type Code])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

You can try it on the following [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b7b83f4ebbfe10159ee862b34fb451b8).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MAX()` for `PIVOT` without aggregation columns.

```
SELECT id, empId, Eclass,StartTime,EndTime, TypeCode
FROM #Emp
PIVOT
(
    MAX(EType)
    FOR code IN ([StartTime],[EndTime],[TypeCode])
) AS P
```

Comment: Following up on your idea, and using MSDN documentation, I came up with the following fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e2292060fc9ef1293e6a3e3eb0671cb. Could this be of help?

Comment: Yes. Fiddle query works. I can point now what I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: Yves, You can post your answer.

Comment: @DineshMadhup it's done. Glad I could be of help.